# How to get distance bw 2 points in real world irrespective of diffrence in height?

Tags: distance

i am using a pair of DW1000 UWB sensors and am able to get accurate distance bw them.
how can i get rid of (z1-z2) term in the final distance..i.e if both sensors are fixed at (x1,y1)and (x2,y2 ) respectively , how do i ensure that the distance (reported ) states constant even if i move the tags up or down

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the (z1-z2) information to the anchor to calculate the horizontal distance. Use Pythagoras' Theorem. If z1-z2 is unknown, you need more sensors.